# Custom block with CMS home page content

Tags: magento2

I can create a custom block then "import" another existing content, example:

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

How can I import the content of my cms home page into a custom block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I have a custom block `Rkt\StackExchange\Block\Main` defined at `app/code/Rkt/StackExchange/Block/Main.php`.

Now include this block within your CMS Page like this:

```
{{block class="Rkt\StackExchange\Block\Main" name="main" page_identifier="no-route" template="Rkt_StackExchange::form.phtml"}}
```

Important points to note here is, I included the `page_identifier` in the bock declaration. The page identifier is your URL key for the CMS page. Other than that I have specified the block type and block template. So let us define both of these files.

### The Template File

File: `app/code/Rkt/StackExchange/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml`

```
<?php echo $block->getPage() ?>
```

As you can see, we are calling the `getPage()` method of block class to render the cms page content.

### The Block Class

File: `app/code/Rkt/StackExchange/Block/Main.php`

```
<?php
namespace Rkt\StackExchange\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Helper\Page as CmsPageHelper;
use Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View as PageControllerView;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Main extends Template
{
    protected $pageIdentifier;

    protected $storeManager;

    protected $pageFactory;

    protected $cmspageHelp;

    protected $request;

    protected $response;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        PageControllerView $request,
        ResponseInterface $response,
        CmsPageHelper $cmspageHelp,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->cmspageHelp = $cmspageHelp;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getPage()
    {
        $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
        $pageId = $page->checkIdentifier(
            $this->getPageIdentifier(), 
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        );
        if (!$pageId) {
            return '';
        }
        $resultPage = $this->cmspageHelp->prepareResultPage($this->request, $pageId);
        return $resultPage->renderResult($this->response);
    }

    public function getPageIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->pageIdentifier;
    }
    public function setPageIdentifier($identifier)
    {
        $this->pageIdentifier = $identifier;
    }
}
```

In the `getPage()` method, we are collecting the identifier, then using CMS Page helper to retrieve the content of the cms page.

### Better Solution

Though the solution above given works for your requirement, I think we are making things complex here. I think the solution put forward by @magento68 seems to be a good solution here.

Or create a static block with the CMS page content that you wish to add in your current CMS page, then just invoke the static block in the CMS Page. This will be simple and easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

Keep below xml in your **cms_index_index.xml** file and check in front,
You have keep same block_identifier for both static block.
You have to keep static block name as unique,

```
<referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block1</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>

    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_identifier-second" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block2</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Replace block1 and block2 with your static block id in above xml code.

***OR***

in admin panel go to Content->Pages and edit home page and if you created your static block from admin panel add following to the Content tab

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="your_block_identifier"}}
```

and if you created a custom block using a module add following to home page content tab

```
{{block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\BlockName" template="Vendor_ModuleName::yourcustomblock.phtml"}}
```

then save the changes and flush magento cache and deploy/delete static contents now refresh home page .

If this was not worked let me know

Comment: Thanks for your help. What's the "block_id" I can use to have all the existing contente from CMS Home page to be added to another block. That´s the question.

Answer (score -1):

There are two way, you can add a block  to home page:

### Via Layout

Create `cms_index_index.xml` at `app/design/frontend/{VendorName}/{themename}/Magebto_Cms/layout` .

***then ad below code at  in this files:***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">4
   <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtm">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    <body/>
</page>
```

### Via admin CMS Page:

*Go to admin panel go to **Content->Pages** ,select your home page and edit home page to the **Content tab***.

> {{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm"
>   template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}

### In this way, you can add any block to home.

Just need to changes  from

> class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm"

to

> class="[Your_Customer_Block_Class_name]"

Also,need to change  template file:

> template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"

to

> template="{VendorName}_{ModuleName}::{templatefilelocatin}/{filename}.phtml"

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I have asked. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you want? what you mean by import?

Comment: Hi Amit, my cms home page is indeed a page (cms/page/view/page_id/2). What I want to do is create a block with the same content that already exists on that page. The reason I want that is because I added a Category named "home page" but I want it to redirect to home page instead of listing produts. So I would set that category to display only a custom block. Tks!

Answer (score -2):

If you have the homepage contents stored in a static block, say "*block_homepage_contents*", you can include that CMS static block in to your custom block.

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="block_homepage_contents"}}
```

Comment: That´s the question. What's the "block_id" I can use to have all the existing contente from CMS Home page to be added to another block.

Comment: this is the way you can add static cms block. In the question custom block i think dynamic block that exist in module